# x tick values truncated when y axis is in log mode

Tags: pgfplots

I have some code similar to this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\begin{filecontents}{data-fake.dat}
xpos    y  date
1       1  09-01
2       3  09-02
3       1  09-03
4       4  09-04
5       2  09-05
6       1  09-06
7       2  09-07
8       0  09-08
9       1  09-09
10      2  09-10
11      1  09-11
12      2  09-12
13      0  09-13
14      1  09-14
15      1  09-15
16      0  09-16
17      2  09-17
18      0  09-18
19      0  09-19
20      0  09-20
21      4  09-21
22      0  09-22
23      0  09-23
24      1  09-24
25      0  09-25
26      0  09-26
27      1  09-27
28      3  09-28
29      1  09-29
30      10  09-30
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\begin{axis}[
width=32cm,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
ymode=log, 
log ticks with fixed point,
xtick=data,
xticklabels from table={data-fake.dat}{date},
x tick label style={rotate=90} 
]
\addplot table[x=xpos,y=y] {data-fake.dat};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Why when the y axis is in log mode the x ticks are printed up to `09-20` ignoring the following ten ticks while the plot in printed correctly?

How do I make all the x ticks appear as they would if the y axis was not in log mode?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have zero values in the Y-column and the logarithm for such values is infinite (`-\infty`). Accordingly, such values are skipped by pgfplots. The dates from the third column are set incorrectly. This can be seen if you display the numerical values (first column) for the X-axis. And for such a set of values (with zeros), you cannot use a logarithmic scale.

Comment: yep, problem was with zero values. Thank you.